# Paths on development and live servers

Tags: path, live, development-environment, mamp, absolute

I'm looking for some advice, I currently use MAMP on locahost and have all of my websites in the htdocs folder. I use Codenighter mainly so when adding in paths for links, images etc I use `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` which is great for using the same code across live and dev.

I was wondering how I can link through to files from within a javascript file and preserve the paths when taking the site up to the live server?

I'm unable to put in absolute paths such as `/controller/` as this doesn't work within the MAMP htdocs folder - I have to use `/mysite/controller/` instead.

Is there a good way to preserve the paths when working across the two servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should setup virtualhosts in Apache.  By far the easiest way to do this is either get MAMP pro, or get VirtualHost X, the later is what I use.  You can certainly setup virtual hosts in the Apache config but VirtualHost X adds the convenience factor.

So for instance if my live site is example.com then I setup a virtual host locally called example.local.